# Unique terms for each vector in R

Tags: r

after searching for a similar question, I couldn't find what I was looking for, that's why I am asking you the following:

- Let's say I have this two vectors in R:

> ```
> x <- c("a","b","c","d")
> y <- c("a", "b", "c")
> ```

- I want to extract all the termns contained in y from x, so the output would be only "d".
- I have two very large data sets, so typing in every term I want to extract doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: setdiff would work better if you're not sure which of the two vectors has the extra elements

Answer (score 2):

`x[x %in% y]` will give all the elements from `x` that **are** in `y`. `x[!x %in% y]` will give all the elements from `x` that are **not** in `y` (which yields your `d` answer). You should also lookup the `intersect`, `union`, `setdiff` and `setequal` functions for these types of "set" operations.